# Route Not Hitting Controller

Tags: laravel, controller, routes, laravel-routing

When I try to create a view for a product, the URL gets built correctly.

```
http://localhost:8000/product/my-slug
```

However, I get a 404 page not found and I have no idea why. It's like the controller is not getting called.

**Initiation**

```
<a href="{{ route('product.view', $product->slug) }}">
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/product/{$slug}', 'ProductsController@view')->name('product.view');
```

**Controller**

```php
public function view($slug)
{
    $product = Product::find($slug);

    return view('products.view', compact('product'));
}
```

**View**

```
<h1>{{ $product->name }}</h1>
```

**EDIT**

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'ProductsController@index')->name('product.index');
Route::get('/products/create', 'ProductsController@create')->name('product.create');
Route::post('/products', 'ProductsController@store')->name('product.store');
Route::get('/product/{$slug}', 'ProductsController@view')->name('product.view');
/*Route::get('/users', 'UsersController');*/

Route::get('/contact', 'PagesController@contact');
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');
```

Comment: Can you show `web.php` content?

Comment: Is your slug column primary key ?

Comment: @Davit web.php is added

Comment: @Md.SukelAli No, that's another issue that needs to be solved. Even if the view function just says `return "test";` I get the 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
Route::get('/product/{$slug}', 'ProductsController@view')->name('product.view');
```

to

```
Route::get('/product/{slug}', 'ProductsController@view')->name('product.view');
```

Ref: [Laravel Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing)

Comment: Yes ! that's the problem. I just checked it in my machine. I suspect that would be the problem but wasn't 100% sure.